# Incorrect datetime value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy intentando insertar unos datos por php a mi base de datos, a la hora de hacer el INSERT me da el siguiente error:

```
Error de MySQL : 1411 : Incorrect datetime value: '21/09/2018' for function 
str_to_date.
```

Dejo el código de inserción:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO control_gasolio.registros 
(nombre,proveedor_gasolio,tipo_gasolio,litros,euros,numero_tarjeta,fecha)
values 
('$nombre','$proveedor','$gasoleo','$litros','$euros','$tarjeta',STR_TO_DATE( 
'$fecha', '%d-%m-%Y' ))";
```

Agradecería algo de ayuda en saber cual puede ser mi error.
Gracias

Comment: Estas intentando guardar una fecha que en el campo de la base de datos espera un fecha con hora y en formato "Año/Mes/Dia"

Comment: He echo una prueba haciendolo directamente en la base de datos con el siguiente codigo y funciona correctamente insertandolo en formato "Año/Mes/Dia":  INSERT INTO control_gasolio.registros (fecha) 
values (STR_TO_DATE('09-10-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')); @Oswuell

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que el error sea indirecto y realmente proceda del propio PHP, desde la consola de mysql puedes probar esto:

`mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`

Esto ignorará el error, de todas maneras es aconsejable realizar un posterior `SELECT` para aclarar si no ha habido algún comportamiento extraño al realizar el `INSERT`.

En otro caso el tipo de dato `DATE` MySQL almacena tu fecha con el siguiente formato: YYYY-MM-DD, considera dejarlo por defecto.

De todas maneras, si aún así no funciona, podrías revisar que el `String` que pasas por PHP no tiene tabulaciones, espacios o directamente copiar y pegar que recibe, por ejemplo haciendo un `echo` ? Así podríamos sacar algo más en claro.

Answer (score 1):

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO control_gasolio.registros 
(nombre,proveedor_gasolio,tipo_gasolio,litros,euros,numero_tarjeta,fecha)
values 
('$nombre','$proveedor','$gasoleo','$litros','$euros','$tarjeta',
STR_TO_DATE(  '$fecha', '%d-%m-%Y' ))";
```

el problema es que tenes que pasarle el mes y el año en mayuscula.

```
'%d-%M-%Y'
```

Comment: por que el mes en mayúscula?